# MySQL referring to own id from within table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two `id` columns and a `name` column the first of the `id` columns is the primary key, the second either refers to a primary key or is NULL.

```
+--+-----+----+
|id|subid|name|
+--+-----+----+
|1 |NULL |Tom |
+--+-----+----+
|2 |1    |Will|
+--+-----+----+
```

Given a name, I would like to, using only one `SQL` statement to output all entries with that given name, but if the secondary `id` field refers to a primary key, to output that entry instead.
Using the above example if I input "Tom" I would like to output `name` = "Tom" and if I input "Will" I would like to output `name` = "Tom" too? 
Is that achievable with one SQL statement only, because I would like to avoid looping through results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You want to use a `join` for this and an expression in the `select`:

```
select t.*
from table t left outer join
     table sub
     on t.subid = sub.id
where 'Tom' = t.name or 'Tom' = sub.name;
```